# Combine - display inline-block and none?

Tags: css

```
div#errors_of_saved{
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    display: none;}
```

There is error div, which is hidden until some JS function doesn't fade it in, and also it should be displayed inline.

The problem - this way text editor says that `display` property is overwritten, and  `display: inline-block none;` - that syntax is invalid.

I don't want to use `visibilty:hidden` because Jquery animation `fadeIn() fadeOut()` doesn't work with visibility.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you want a jQuery solution that specifically illustrates how to use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`?

Answer (score 0):

Because `div#errors_of_saved` is displayed on demand to show error messages, I would set the default to `display: none`.

jQuery tends to use `display: block` to show an element.  Since you want to use `display: inline-block`, I might try setting a more specific CSS rule, for example:

```
div#errors_of_saved.show {
    display: inline-block
}
```

and then have jQuery add the class as needed to show the error message.

My suggestion assumes that you might use the jQuery `animate()` function, but there are several approaches one could try.